# ASP.NET MVC 3. Validation doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 two pages.
First page

```
@model IncidentsDB.UI.Web.ViewModels.Account.LogOnModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Вход в систему";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="headerLabel">            
    <h3>Вход в систему</h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "searchForm" }))    
{
    <div class="createUserDiv">
        <input type="submit" class="lightGreenGradientBtn" id="createUserBtn" value="Добавить нового пользователя" />
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div class="loginDataDiv">
        <div class="leftItemDiv labelDiv" style="padding-left: 45px">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field rightItemDiv">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)            
        </div>
         <div class="loginErrorDiv  labelDiv">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="leftItemDiv  labelDiv" style="padding-left: 45px">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field rightItemDiv noWrap">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)                         
        </div>
        <div class="rememberPswdDivCollapse" id="rememberPswdDiv">                                     
            @Html.ActionLink("Вспомнить пароль", "RestorePassword","Account", new { @class = "rememberPswdLink" })                                 
        </div>        
        <div class="loginErrorDiv">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>        
        <div class="clearStyles rightItemDiv">                
            <input type="submit" class="greenGradientBtn" id="loginBtn" value="Войти" />                
        </div>            
    </div>
}
```

and second page

```
@model IncidentsDB.UI.Web.ViewModels.Account.LogOnModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Вход в систему";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="restorePswdDivVisible">
        <p>
            Введите адрес электронной почты, <br />
            который вы указывали при регистрации:
        </p>
          <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
        <div class="editor-field noWrap">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) 
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="loginErrorDiv noWrap" style="width: 150px">

        </div>
        <div>
           <input type="submit" class="lightGreenGradientBtn restorePswdBtn" id="restorePswdBtn" value="Восстановить"  style="margin-left: 150px" />                
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

also I have model class which is general for two pages

```
namespace IncidentsDB.UI.Web.ViewModels.Account
{
    public class LogOnModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Укажите логин")]
        [Display(Name = "NicName", ResourceType = typeof(PersonalRes))]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Укажите пароль")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(PersonalRes))]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Укажите e-mail")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(PersonalRes))]
        public string Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Rememberme", ResourceType = typeof(PersonalRes))]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

so this code works fine in firefox and chrome, but doesn't in ie!
why?

thanks in advance!

Comment: you have two forms on page one, and both have submit buttons, and when a `submit` type button is clicked it submits all forms on a page(atleast in IE), so try changing the input type `submit` to `button` and submit the form using JavaScript.

Comment: @furqan that shouldn't be the case. Seems unlikely since each form could have a different action location....how could you then possibly submit to three locations without Ajax then. A submit button should submit the form that contains it.... Even in IE and I know that works as expected in IE.

Comment: In what way does the validation not work in IE?